# Why is my StreamReader reading the title of the text file?

Tags: vb.net, email

So I'm working on my A Level coursework and have hit a block that I can't seem to work out. Basically, I have a bit of code that sends an email using text from a text file as well as a bit of hard coded text, all put into one variable before being passed onto the subroutine for sending an email.

I'm using a stream reading for both the email subject and body (as they're each in separate text files) and, while they're working fine elsewhere in the program, they're not working here. Rather than putting the contents of the text file into the variable before it's used to send an email, they're just putting the name of the text file there.

Also, the name of the file does not appear anywhere in the text stored within

E.g. The body of the email that it sent had the hard coded message and then it just said 'AbsenceEmailBody' (name of the text file) rather than what was inside the text file itself

Here's the lines of code where the files are read and put into variables

```
Dim objReaderSubject As New System.IO.StringReader("AbsenceEmailSubject")
Dim objReaderBody As New System.IO.StringReader("AbsenceEmailBody")

Dim EmailBody As String
Dim EmailSubject As String

        EmailBody = "Dear " & CadetDS.Tables("CADET").Rows(0).Item("CadetFirstName") & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "It has come to the staff's attention that you have attended only " & ProblemAttendances(i, 1, 0, 0, 0) & "% of sessions." & vbNewLine & objReaderBody.ReadToEnd

        EmailSubject = objReaderSubject.ReadToEnd
```

I also check the files exist before any of this

```
If System.IO.File.Exists("AbsenceEmailSubject") = True And System.IO.File.Exists("AbsenceEmailBody") = True Then
```

I've looked around everywhere and can't seem to find an answer. Also, this is my first time ever asking a question on here (or anywhere online) so if you need any more information just ask

Comment: `StreamReader` as in the title or `StringReader` as in the code?  `StringReader - Implements a System.IO.TextReader that reads from a string.`... (not a file)  From intellisense

Comment: Oh wow I am such a donut. It should be stream reader in the code. I've changed it and it's all working fine now. Knew it would be something tiny that I overlooked! Thank you for pointing out, might have to delete this question out of shame lol